# Ubuntu - running headless with VNC, also NetworkManager slowly 'locking down' (grey buttons)

Tags: networkmanager

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB - so an 8GB quad-core ARM system. I have installed Ubuntu-Mate 64-bit on this; the installation is done with the 'official' Ubuntu-Mate 64-bit image.

I am having problems with the networking; I managed to mess up the configuration files, resulting in a clean re-install. But the problem is still present.

The main issue right now is that I link the Pi to my MacBook. I have installed VNC on the Pi (TightVNC), and control it that way. It logs in automatically. I am also using 'plain' Ethernet to send VNC data (because I am using ethernet from MacBook to Pi with a short cable). I should SSH and I will, once I get over the teething problems.

Essentially, the 'network' (wifi) icon on the Pi stays in the 'searching' mode when the cable is plugged in.

The syslog basically shows:

```
- policy: autoactivating connection 'Ethernet Connection 1' (______________________)
- (eth0) - Activation : starting connection 'Ethernet Connection 1'
```

(then some more lines)

```
- dhcp4 (eth0) : activation : beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

(then some more lines, and 45 seconds later:)

```
- dhcp4 (eth0) : request timed out
```

The above repeats every 45 seconds. I have made two connection (Ethernet Connection 1 and Wired Connection 1), which is good because it alternates between the two for several minutes before disconnecting...

The connections are configured as IPv4 with IPv6 disabled, and full manual configuration with no DHCP selected at all. They both have the same IP, and settings, and the problem (45-second DHCP timeout) happened prior and still happens with just one configuration.

When the Ethernet connection 'properly' fails (every 1-5 minutes), it can be restarted by unplugging and plugging in the network cable.

I would be grateful for advice on how to stop wired network connections from searching for DHCP, then doing 45-second timeout (noting that the connections are 'manual' IPv4 with specifically chose address, and no DHCP in use).

In addition to the above issue, it is frustrating that the NetworkManager applet gradually 'locks down'; initially 'enable networking' and 'enable wifi' are ticked.

After perhaps 30 minutes from a fresh install, they become 'greyed out' but still ticked. However, it is still possible to add new connections etc using the applet.

However, perhaps 30-90 minutes later, when clicking 'Edit Connections' on the NM applet, the connections (wifi and wired) show, but even when selecting them, the '-' and 'config' buttons are greyed out - but it still lets you add new connections.

However, again 30-90 minutes later, when clicking 'add' new connection, the 'add' window has everything greyed out except 'cancel'.

And then 30-90 minutes later, the 'Edit Connections' and 'Connection Information' options become greyed out.

The above is repeatable, both when not updating packages, or when updating everything immediately after install over wifi.

I would be grateful for advice on how to manually configure Ethernet connections in NetworkManager from the command line - in the context of the applet 'locking down' as above.

If anyone has more info on what might be going wrong (on a plain vanilla install) I would be grateful too!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a fresh install of Ubuntu, and configuration files more or less in their default state, you can do the following. First, use `nmcli d` to get some details about your current networking setup,namely the name of your ethernet device, as I will be using the default `eth0`

#### 1. Start by looking at your `/etc/network/interfaces` file

There is a file located at `/etc/network/interfaces` path which is one of the most fundamental configuration files for NetworkManager, as it provides details regarding configuration when using `ifup` and `ifdown` commands.

In its default state, the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` will most look like so:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).


# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The first part is responsible for the localhost connection loopback and you should leave it alone, but the second part is of interest to you.

If you use NetworkManager to manage connections, its configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` will say:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

and will refer to that `interfaces` file for configuration.

`auto eth0` means bring interface `eth0` up, and `auto [interface name]` lines are normally brought up at startup.

`allow-hotplug eth0` means bring up network interface `eth0` when `udev` detects new network cable being plugged in.

`iface eth0 inet dhcp` means networking interface(iface) `eth0` , using IPv4 networking (inet), will having its address assigned with (dhcp).

---

#### 2. Disable DHCP for your ethernet connection.

In order for eth0 to use a static ip address, the last line `iface eth0 inet dhcp` will need to be changed (I don't know your IP addressing format so I am going to use the common default and you can change that accordingly) to:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.123/24
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

address `192.168.1.2/24` sets both the IP and the netmask to `255.255.255.0` and the last line specifies the gateway at `192.168.1.1`

Once you make the changes with `sudo` privileges, save the `interfaces` file.

#### 3. Restart both networking services on the machine

Execute:

```
sudo service networking restart && sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

The `networking` service, if you look at its `.service` file actually executes `ifup -a --read-environment` which references `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

#### 4. What does this mean for connections you made through the GUI connection manager

When you have `iface eth0 inet dhcp` in `interfaces` along with `allow-hotplug` then the moment you plug your ethernet cable in, the system will try to obtain a proper IP address from DHCP server. Since your Mac does not appear to have a DHCP server running, the connection will eventually suffer a timeout. The reason why you can wake it up when replugging the connector is because `udev` will again sense the new device, and `ifup` will be called to try to bring it up.

This timeout behavior is typical when connecting a PC to any embedded device for network transmission with neither running a DHCP server for addressing. However as long as you first manually assign a static IP to the embedded device (Raspberry Pi) from the same subnet as the PC, the transmission will work just fine.

The wireless interface `wlan0` will be held by this `eth0` timeout.

Under normal circumstances and with more or less default post-install settings, the GUI connection manager and its corresponding profiles for `eth0` will always come second to what is in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, as that will be read the moment you plug your ethernet cable in.

---

**Changing IP addressing from `dhcp` to a `static` in `/etc/network/interfaces` and restarting the networking services should solve your problem**